# Rasa core tensorflow dependency

Tags: tensorflow, rasa-core

i am following this [link](https://vimeo.com/254777331) for creating chatbot using RASA. However when i am facing issue while installing rasa core. I am getting error like

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow~=1.12.0 (fr
om rasa_core) (from versions: 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow~=1.12.0 (from rasa_core)
```

I am having tensorflow 1.13. I tried downgrading also but it is not able to find tensorflow 1.12.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've got python 3.7 installed, tensorflow doesn't support this yet, downgrade to 3.6 and the issue should be resolved!

@ironman in case you are using Anaconda (conda), you can get downgrade simply by using the following command.

`conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`

conda will take care of all dependencies like upgrade/downgrade etc.